# in Java return by condition

Tags: java

I couldn't figure out the following code, is that mean if `this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username)` not equal to `null` then make `this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username)` equal to `null`?

```
public boolean isUsernameAvailable(String username) {
    return this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) == null;
}
```

Comment: please give some context

Comment: What do you mean by "make it null"?

Comment: no, its: "when blalah is null, then return `true`, `false` otherwise" ;) (only comparison and return , no assignment)

Comment: @xerx593 okay, just to make sure I understood correct,  if this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) null then return true, otherwise return false right?

Comment: Note `=` (a single equals sign) is assignment (a statement); `==` is comparison (an expression) {{roughly speaking}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that mean if this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) not equal to null make it null?

No.  The expression `this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) == null` computes `this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username)` and determines whether the result is equal to `null`.  The result of the null check is a `boolean` value, `true` if the result of `getUserByUsername()` was `null` and `false` otherwise.  This `boolean` result is the return value of `isUsernameAvailable()`.

Answer (score 1):

No It is referring to an HasAObject {userMapper} and calling a method getUserByUsername which takes the argument username. When you get the username then run a comparison to null based on the result return the Boolean result.

Comment: if this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) null then return true, otherwise return false right?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple boolean function which states isUsernameAvailable and further on calling  this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username), if it is null then they condition become null == null which becomes true and the function will return true but if this.userMapper.getUserByUsername(username) this call return something then return value will become false.